# combining data in several rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the same participant (person_id) attached to a variable amount of rows of data. I need to return the different data for the same column no matter how many times this person entered the data and do this for over 20,000 entrants in one report.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Throw up some code my friend.  If you don't, your question could get booted.

Comment: Sounds like you may need `group_concat`. Example data and desired results are needed though.

Answer (score 0):

You asked the question later too? and not giving more info here:
[Combining Records in a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781156/combining-records-in-a-query)